# Account tab hides accounts with more than 200 reputation on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, linked-accounts, stackexchange.com

In [Stack Exchange main site](https://stackexchange.com/), under the accounts tab there is a list of accounts with more than 200 reputation points, and button "show accounts with less than 200 reputation".

[image: account list]

For some reason, meta stackoverflow with more than 200 points is not shown:

[image: After clicking "show accounts with less..."]

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accounts tab on the SE user page operates on a ~1-day delay, and since you passed the 200-rep threshold during the past day, it hasn't been updated to include your MSO account yet.

When you click "show accounts with less than 200 reputation", the entire page is updated to show the up-to-the-second status of all your accounts, which is causing your MSO account to suddenly appear with >200 rep. I agree that this behavior is slightly confusing -- we'll be rolling out a backend overhaul of the SE user page in a couple weeks, which will greatly reduce the delay and eliminate the inconsistency between before/after clicking "show accounts...".

Comment: I assume this also holds for accounts I linked to my carreers profile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a delay of approximatively 1 day before it will get update on SE.
I suppose this is for optimisation of performances.

Comment: Yes, SE is updated daily (so reputation points and badges etc. come with one day delay). However, now it's already updated.